# Magento 2 Installation Error (PHP Settings Check *)

Tags: compiler-errors, installation, magento2

Your PHP Version is 5.6.30-1+deb.sury.org~xenial+1, but always_populate_raw_post_data = 0. $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is deprecated from PHP 5.6 onwards and will be removed in PHP 7.0. This will stop the installer from running. Please open your php.ini file and set always_populate_raw_post_data to -1. If you need more help please call your hosting provider

I Uploaded all the required print screen 
**Error Page:**
[image]

**PHP info file**

[image]

**My php.ini file**

[image]

Comment: The `;` is a comment. It means anything following it will be ignored. Remove the `;`.

Comment: I just open the php.ini file and look the same i did not changed anything

Comment: Remove the `;`.

Answer (score 0):

did you put it on -1? because now it is put in comment. try to remove ';' in front of the line.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible you have different settings for the PHP CLI and the PHP web server plug-in. Use [this troubleshooting topic](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/prereq/php-settings.html) to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just enable php.ini.sample to php.ini on root

and add

```
always_populate_raw_post_data to -1
```

at last in php.ini.